# Do you "stand/get on" or "stand/get up on" a higher object?

Tags: word-request, phrasal-verbs

I feel a bit embarrassed to ask this question after all the years of learning English, but do you "stand/get on" or "stand/get **up** on" a higher object (for example, a bench)? I mean when you change your position.

Comment: Both are correct. The addition of the particle changes the meanimg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you:

> (just) sit (or stand) on a bench/ a chair/ a couch / a bed

> climb onto (or over) a table/ a gate / a wall or similar obstacle

> climb through a window

> climb a ladder/ a mountain

> climb up a tree/ a rope

> mount, get (up) onto, a horse / donkey etc

**Scale** is often used (transitively) instead of **climb**, especially when challenging climbs are involved.

You can ** get onto** or **step onto/over** any object that requires you to mount something, a stile for example.

You **get into** a vehicle / clamber or climb (up) into a truck.

And many more.

(Don't get into a pickle over prepositions)

Comment: If you change your position so that you are no longer standing on the floor and instead standing on a bench, are any of my proposals correct or is there no way around 'onto' (to be frank, I just forgot that preposition)? And can I use 'onto' with 'stand'? Can it describe that kind of motion or does it only refer to a stationary state (other meanings aside)?